# Connect dual Monitors to a single USB-C Port

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb

How can I connect dual monitors with DVI or Display Port or HDMI to my single USB-C Port on my 2016 MacBook?

Comment: have you found out how to connect two monitors (both HDMI/DVI) to one single USB-C port?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Macbook 2016 but you could try [this](http://www.apple.com/au/shop/product/MB571Z/A/mini-displayport-to-dual-link-dvi-adapter?fnode=11d5e277bb5a1764c727b86760a71fd618a925157424b65dcd5d89e0e81dc300324d2556c36ee198bf6ff1a80cf04b07dcf988b4d0fa7d7769337a11f2bec4a165934ad3c3233754ad9c1878c9fcd7d3872db23c7630c3a765e03a8be5c7b579) (or more cheaply a third party cable that converts USB3A to DVI/DisplayPort/HDMI) connected to [this](http://www.apple.com/au/shop/product/MJ1K2ZA/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter?fnode=56c21283d62f79a8f0741ab5cc51092ccd08fcd994ec4ef918a3f6cacd0a80a9c77fc4820d5b1d36803d262e65a4bae3aab086ec814eb5488c1495952a8fd9afc258591dcc25f72e3b3a4b3fd8e0f42ef67fcedc8970cf11c98386f2eefc167c) connected to your Macbook.

You may want to look at the review for the second one. Apparently it has some reliability issues.

Answer (score 1):

The 2016 Macbook doesn't support more than 1 external display.  From [Everymac.com](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-m7-1.3-12-early-2016-specs.html):

[image]

However, that being said, I have seen folks add a second screen (a second projector) using a [USB to video adapter](http://radnex.us/startech-usb-dvi-adapter).

[image]

I have never had the need or opportunity to try this myself, so YMMV.